# Install outside spigot from PEX piping

Tags: pex

I want to install an outside spigot from my PEX piping inside the house. The previous line was extracted, and I can't find where it was to follow that same route. However, my basement window is boarded with a hole in the center, and I figure I can route it out that way, and mount the spigot to the outside of the house some way to secure it. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you have freezing temperatures?

Comment: What's the actual key question? This site isn't "how to be a plumber"

Comment: Cute @whatsisname. Out of all the plumbing questions I've seen on here, and you pick on me. Haha! Like I asked. How do I install a line for an outside spigot from the PEX line in my house? I appreciate the response. Maybe I wasn't as clear in my inquiry as I thought I was.

Comment: No, I don't have freezing temps @crip659. I'm just trying to install an outside spigot I can use for the back yard, gardening, wash the dogs, etcetera.

Comment: You will want an elbow right outside of the window, and then an elbow with mounting holes/wings where you want the spigot to be.  It should be down hill or as far as the window as possible.  A leaking spigot no fun at/near a basement window.  It would be better to drill though the wall where you want the spigot, but do not know how the house is built.  Most have wood above cement.

Comment: It's a stone basement @crip659. Thanks for answering my question. It's in poor condition. I've had issues with field mice chewing through. the mortar.I've been sealing it where I can find entry points inside and out.

Comment: Sounds like you need to bring out the big 50 cablier guns.  I would suggest copper or maybe galvanized piping outside, since you do not have freezing temps.  Never use metal pipes in freezing temps.